# Get sum of quantity in mongodb using yii2 framework

Tags: mongodb, yii2, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can i **sum of quantity** using `mongodb` query in `yii2`?

In my database there are entries like below:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId("560e36f91e4acbf113d14f1f"),
    'user_id': '55ded7c31e4acbea3c8b4567',
    'money': '1.99',
    'quantity': '1',
    'purchased_date_time': '2015-10-02 07:49:13'
}    

{
    '_id': ObjectId("560e36f71e4acbf113d14f1e"),
    'user_id': '55ded7c31e4acbea3c8b4567',
    'money': '1.99',
    'quantity': '1',
    'purchased_date_time': '2015-10-02 07:49:11'
}    

{
    '_id': ObjectId("560d17381e4acbf013d14f1e"),
    'user_id': '55ded7c31e4acbea3c8b4567',
    'money': '4.99',
    'quantity': '3',
    'purchased_date_time': '2015-10-01 11:21:28'
}
```

I want to sum of quantity where `user_id = 55ded7c31e4acbea3c8b4567`.

What i tried is:

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('purchase');
        $result = $collection->aggregate(
            array( '$match' => array( 'user_id' => '55ded7c31e4acbea3c8b4567') ),
            array( '$group' => array( '_id' => NULL,
                'quantity' => array( '$sum' => (int)'$quantity' )
                ))
            );
```

But always i am getting this result:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 
            [quantity] => 0
        )    
)
</pre>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You're on the right track for the type of query to issue, but your problem is your data is "strings" and not numeric values. So you cannot add up strings and you cannot cast a string as a number. You need to fix the data.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i do that?

Comment: You clearly have multiple problems, being first to convert the data and then to find the code responsible for writing it this way. Or is this just the result of an import process.

Comment: in mongodb, it saves data in this format

Comment: No "it" does not. Your code or process is responsible and until you understand what is responsible for writing this way then conversion is of little help. `'55ded7c31e4acbea3c8b4567'` should be an `ObjectId`, `'2015-10-01 11:21:28'` should be a BSON Date, and of course the other valules should be numeric. If this was normal then you wouldn't have received this response. As a guess, you have some code somewhere that serializes data as JSON, then you convert this back and insert. That's the wrong thing to do.

Comment: means i have to save quantity in integer?

Comment: Correct. And that you should look at what is happening with the other types as well. If this was just an import then I would straight away recommend conversion. But I think it's fair to suspect since you cannot confirm otherwise that this is being written this way by other application code, and possibly because you thought you have to. You really should clarify this in your question, or even ask a question about how to correct the code that is writing this if you still do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Remove int  then after check......
I solved my issue after remove it

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('purchase');
$result = $collection->aggregate(
    array( '$match' => array( 'user_id' => '55ded7c31e4acbea3c8b4567') ),
    array( '$group' => array( '_id' => NULL,
                              'quantity' => array( '$sum' => '$quantity' )
          ))
);
```